# Android navigation drawer - mixed choiceMode

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've got a simple activity that shows a map.
I'd like to implement a navigation drawer that shows a set of options with `choiceMode="multipleChoice"` (to activate some layers upon the map) and also another set of options with `choiceMode="singleChoice"` (to launch new activities).

The behavior of the drawer should be something similar to the one of the google maps app.

[image]

Any advice would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

You can put a ListView in there, but if you you don't have that many items to show (i.e. the user won't have to scroll it up and down), you could just as easily use a set of checkboxes.